# organizar una consulta de mongoose por un determinado valor

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, sql, mongoose

Tengo una inquietud ¿es posible ordenar una consulta donde los primeros resultados sea donde un campo es igual a un determinado valor? me explico, tengo los siguientes documentos en una colección

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "juan",
    telefono: "324234324"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "pedro",
    telefono: "434345345"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "juan",
    telefono: "23423423"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "andres",
    telefono: "343234"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "juan",
    telefono: "23432432"
  }
]
```

me llega por variable el name juan, como podría hacer que se organice la consulta por ese valor, es decir, que los primeros objetos de esa consulta, sean todos los documentos sonde su "name" sea "juan", dando como resultado algo como lo siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "juan",
    telefono: "324234324"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "juan",
    telefono: "23432432"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "juan",
    telefono: "23423423"
  }
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "pedro",
    telefono: "434345345"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    name: "andres",
    telefono: "343234"
  }
]
```

¿es posible hacerlo desde la consulta con mongoose? ¿o no hay de otra que organizar la consulta después de obtener los resultados en desorden desde la base de datos?
no sé si me hice entender.

gracias de antemano.

Comment: Claro, la función se llama Sort. Te dejo enlace de la documentación de MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort

Comment: No, con `sort` ordenará los documentos de forma ascendente o descendente, eso no implica que pondrá `juan` de primero, a menos que el resto de nombres sean lexicográficamente mayores que `juan`, por ejemplo `juana, julia, julio` etc, y no existan nombres que sean menores (lexicográficamente) como por ejemplo `andreś, ernesto, jaime`. La solución es otra, @Batuza. Saludos